# Seeking location based social network dataset

Tags: data

I'm looking for a dataset of Geosocial network consisting of GPS trajectories, check-in, geotag contents and stuff like these available for research purposes.

Can you can point me towards such a reliable dataset?

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/)? [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/geo-developer-guidelines) is some more information on the geographic components of the data and API.

Answer (score 2):

While not as lively as twitter, [Findagrave.com](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GSln=sauer&GSfn=carl&GSbyrel=all&GSdyrel=all&GSob=n&GRid=12713336&df=all&) has a lot of from-nodes and to-nodes (place of birth, place of death). Given the large numbers of graves at this site, it seems like a variety of migration maps could be generated.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap stores GPS tracks http://www.openstreetmap.org/traces generated by mappers, but nothing like checkins or social stuff in the "2.0" sense.

For that kind of social-media resources you should see every social network API to see if they provide geographic information. Twitter, Foursquare, gowalla, yelp, all do it.

Not sure also what you mean by a "*reliable data set*" in this context.